# JQuery two different conditions are true. How to execute first condition only if its already true?

Tags: jquery, if-statement

Both of these conditions are true, what happen here is after the 1st condition it will automatically execute the other condition. I want to execute only the first condition if its true and disregard the other condition. Already tried with 'else if' but not getting my desired result.

```
var productType = 'virtual';

var customerCredits = '150';
var totalPrice = '100';

    if(productType == 'virtual'){
      //some statements
    }
    if(customerCredits>totalprice){
     //some statements

}
```

Comment: You should change `customerCredits = '150'` to `customerCredits = 150` no need have customerCredits as a string. same goes for totalPrice. Basicly `customerCredits>totalprice` is equal to `'150'>'100'`

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen okay thanks, but how do i stick to the 1st condition if it is already true and disregard the next condition?

Comment: use an else if? `if () {} else if () {}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`else if` works well. Apart from this replace 'totalprice' in condition with 'totalPrice'

```js
var productType = 'virtual';

var customerCredits = 150;
var totalPrice = 100;

    if(productType == 'virtual'){
      console.log('a')
    } else
    if(customerCredits>totalPrice){
     console.log('b')

}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Why add jquery link. No jquery in the code?

Comment: if you mean why jquery is included, snippet has automatically added it when i ran it.
if you mean why i am using jquery, because the question itself tagged with jquery